# Using Hivelogic MySQL again after installing Homebrew

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, homebrew, chown

I previously installed mysql using the Hivelogic compilation method.

http://hivelogic.com/articles/compiling-mysql-on-snow-leopard/

Then I installed Homebrew. Which broke it. Here's why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it says in [Installing to /usr/local for Developers](https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation), homebrew `chown`s everything under /usr/local to your user. MySQL uses the mysql user - bringing incompatibility.

`sudo chown -R /usr/local/mysql /usr/local/mysql/*` for the win.